# Twitter API OAuth File upload gives error 'You must supply a readable file'

Tags: php, file-upload, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I've followed [this](https://twitteroauth.com) tutorial to make a media upload to the twitter API. The text upload works perfectly, but if I want to upload a media, I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'You must supply a readable file' in /hp/be/ac/on/www/vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:297 Stack trace: #0 /hp/be/ac/on/www/vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php(266): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->uploadMediaNotChunked('https://upload....', Array) #1 /hp/be/ac/on/www/posten.php(288): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->upload('https://upload....', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /hp/be/ac/on/www/vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 297

This is my code:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(
    $config['consumer_key'],
    $config['consumer_secret'],
    $OAuthToken,
    $OAuthTokenSecret
);

$post_media = $twitter->upload('media/upload', ['media' => "/uploads/Bilder/1.png"]);

/**$parameters = [
    'status' => "Test description",
    'media_ids' => implode(',', [$post_media->media_id_string])
];

$result = $twitter->post('statuses/update', $parameters);**/
```

Like you see, I've even commented the part, beginning at `$parameters`, but that didn't change the result. So the error must be in the upload line.
I've already tried replacing `media/upload` with `https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json` as said in https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/562, but that didn't help either.
I've checked, that the link `/uploads/Bilder/1.png` is correct and refers to an image on my server. So, why doesn't the script work?

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `/uploads/Bilder/1.png` is correct? That `/` at the start means the root directory of your server.  As your error message starts with `/hp/be/ac/on/www/` I wonder if the file is located elsewhere - or whether PHP is allowed to access that location.

Comment: @TerenceEden In the browser I find the picture on https://myWebsi.te/uploads/Bilder/1.png
But when I replaced `/uploads/Bilder/1.png` with `/hp/be/ac/on/www/uploads/Bilder/1.png`, it worked! So thank you!
I assumed, that the twitter API will grab the picture externally, so I postet the external link. But internally, the whole webspace is save into `/hp/be/ac/on/www/`, so I didn't even think about providing this link.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Woo! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's late to answer, but might help someone. The code below works just perfect!

```
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $twitter->get("account/verify_credentials");
$tweet = "My tweet";
$imageMedia = $twitter->upload('media/upload', array('media' => '/path/to/image/image_name.png'));
$parameters = array("status" => $tweet, "media_ids" => $imageMedia->media_id_string);

$statuses = $twitter->post("statuses/update", $parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, different solution.

Answer: "**The upload() function requires a local file. An URL will not work, you must download it first.**"

Look at this issue: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/697

Answer (score -1):

If you want to post image using twitter api at first you must download it first. In fact the upload() function requires a local file.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62307013/2227743).